# How to change the route according to the value of a field

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a search page in an application with several pages, I use react router v5.

My problem is the following, I would like to return to the previous page when a text field is empty otherwise if there is an entry in the input field, I want to return to the search page ('/search')

I thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

So I used goBack and push props.
But the return to the previous page does not work even when the field is empty

My component Routes.js

```
 const Routes = (props) => {
    return (
       <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route
             exact
             path='/search'
             component={() => <Search query={props.text} />}
          />
          <Route path="/film/:id" component={MovieDetail} />  
          <Route path="/FavorisList" component={WatchList} />
          <Route path="/search/:search" component={Search} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />  
       </div>

  )}
```

My component SearchBar.js

```
  class SearchBar extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.state = {
            inputValue:'',
         };

       }

      handleChange = (event) => {

          if(event.target.value === '') {
              this.props.history.goBack()
              return;
          }

          if(event.target.value.length){
             this.props.history.push("/search")
             this.search(event.target.value)
          }
       }

       search = (query) => {
           //search results retrieved with redux 
           this.props.applyInitialResult(query, 1)
       }

       render() {
          return (
            <div>
               <input
                   type="text"
                   value={this.state.inputValue}
                   placeholder="Search movie..."
                   className={style.field}
                   onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
               />  
            </div>
          );
        }


       export default SearchBar;
```

Component App.js

```
       class App extends React.Component {
          render(){
              return (
                 <div>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                       <NavBar />
                       <Routes/>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                 </div>
              );
           }
        }

        export default App;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No I do not have an error message, I have unexpected behavior, if I enter a character, the return is done well but when I enter longer terms like "mission impossible" the return is no longer done .

Comment: I don't see any reference to `SearchBar` in your routes. Is the `SearchBar` component used in your application ?

Comment: My search bar is integrated in my navigation bar, 
I updated my post with the App component, if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you push new entry to `history` on every change event. So if you e.g. enter 3 characters then 3 the same entries are pushed to `history` stack. As a result when you then call `history.goBack` it redirects to previous entry in history stack which is `/search` in your case (so you remain on the current page).

You can think of history stack as array which holds entries - when you have entered 3 characters this array will look like this:
`['/someInitialPath', '/search', '/search', '/search']`
Calling `goBack` redirects to previous path in history stack so if you now call `goBack` you get the path pointing to the `/search` path which is current page and as a result you see no change. You would get redirected to `/someInitialPath` if you called `goBack` 3 times in this case.

Solution is to call `history.push` only on first `change` event. You can add additional field to `state` indicating whether `handleChange` is called for the first time. Something like this:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);

         this.state = {
            inputValue:'',
            initialChange: true
         };

      }

      handleChange = (event) => {

          if(event.target.value === '') {
              this.props.history.goBack()
              this.setState({ initialChange: true }) // clear flag after redirect
              return;
          }

          if(event.target.value.length && this.state.initialChange){
             this.setState({
               initialChange: false
             }, () => {
               this.props.history.push("/search")
               this.search(event.target.value)
             })

          }
       }
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Yes I think you're right, but how can I prevent this page change at every event on Change.

If this can help you, I want to reproduce what netflix do for their search system, I do not know if react router is the best solution.

Comment: I've updated answer with draft of solution. React-router is good choice, actually your problem is not caused by this or other lib so it doesn't matter if you use react-router or any other routing lib. But react-router is most popular lib for this. Detailed solution might be more complex but it depends on other requirements. But  I do hope my answer solves problem from your question.

Comment: Hello I just tried your solution, it works the first time, but as I want to do a new search, I do not return to the search page.

Comment: I've just updated with improved version (added clearing flag). Please try this.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! it works, so I have another concern now, how can I save the state of my search page, when I refresh the application, I stay on my search page but I lost my search results and the value of my input fields.

Comment: Great :) So please accept my answer and upvote it please. I'm sorry but you have to create new  SO post with your question because this is something not related with your orignal question. One answer per question - this is how SO works. I can't answer all your concerns in one post and in comments.

Comment: I have already put a vote, I will create a new post for this question.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: I created a new post for my second question, again thanks for your help => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483582/how-to-update-the-url-of-a-page-using-an-input-field